# MacBook Pro 13" 2011 not booting -- question mark folder

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

My MacBook Pro is not booting. It only shows me a question mark folder. If I try to manually boot, it doesn't give me any options than to go into recovery. And if I go into recovery and then disk utility, it looks like the drive isn't even connected. Has anyone experienced this before? Could it be that the hdd cable is faulty and should be changed? I doubt this is a software problem.

Comment: Is the partition visible if you hold down option (⌥) while booting?

Answer (score 1):

Folder showing `?` means, that there is no bootable system found on your hard disk.

Booting in `Recovery Mode` means, that your HDD is still working.

`Disk Utility` not showing HDD means, that there is no formatted HDD.

To recover your data try following step:

- Shut down computer
- Turn on again pressing `"T"`-Key down till `Firewire Icon` is shown.
- Take another Mac and a Firewire-Cable
- Turn off "new" Mac
- Plug your "Firewire"-Mac into the "New"-Mac

Hopefully, your "Firewire"-Mac will show up as an external Drive.

go [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1661) for detailed information